# How do I Unit Test an infinitely waiting listener?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, moles

I am using MSTest, Vs2010. I have a situation where a method with a while loop calls [AutoResetEvent.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.waitone%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I can trigger this event from my Test method; it will iterate one time and then again wait for this event to be triggered.

I am unable to assert anything in this situation. How can I Unit Test these kind of methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Task` in your unit test to initialise the loop in a separate thread.

```
public void TestMyLoop()
{

    var myLooper = new Looper();

    Task t = Task.Run(() => myLooper.BeginWorking());  // BeginWorking is an infinite loop, it will never end!

    myLooper.AddAnItemToProcess(new Item());

    Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait 5 seconds, alternatively hook into and `await` some completion event.

    // assert here
    Assert.That(myLooper.processedItems == 1);

 }
```

Comment: it looks promising, will definitely give it a try and will update You guys. Thanks

Comment: This result was also useful for my situation where I have an delegate fired inside a while loop (monitoring file transfer), which would only break once the file transfer is completed. Using the above approach, I was able to 'mock' the upload completion and finish the transfer. Using a separate thread is a simple solution!